# Ubuntu gone along with windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bootloader, mbr, wubi

I had earlier installed ubuntu 17.04 using wubi and later on uninstalled it, after restarting my laptop post uninstall the windows 10 is not booting and is stuck at spinning circles. Please help!

Comment: Per [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) Wubi is not supported on Windows 8 (and above). This is due to the hybrid sleep and fastboot methods used on these systems and corruption can occur. You should get a Windows bootable USB and see if it can recover or repair your install. It was also never updated to support Windows 8 so it could have made changes to your bootloader configuration while uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a auto-repair function within its Installer.
Download Windows 10 (e.g. here http://www.chip.de/downloads/Windows-10-64-Bit_72189999.html) und flash it to an usb drive.
Then boot it, select the Repair-Options and then the Bootloader / Autorepair Options.